# Issue with generated react build from react-scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I created react project with react-scripts. After done some functionality, I tried to build the project. For this, I used npm run build command. When I run this command, I can able to generate build folder.

Now, I moved build folder to my server and tried to execute. It's give me blank white screen and saying index.js not found.

I am not sure, how to resolve this issue. Can you please help me. thanks.